# How to change the order of added elements by clicking the button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help with following code. I have to add new li elements and them swap elements by clicking on img up or down. I need to do it dynamically. Thank you so much.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".p-title").hide().fadeIn(1500);
 const nameInput = document.querySelector('#f-name');
 nameInput.focus();
 
 $('form').on('submit', e=>{
  e.preventDefault(); 
  let name = nameInput.value; 
  addItem(name);
 })
 let addItem = (name)=>{
  $('#list').append('<li>'+name+'<img src="/assets/img/site/up_arrow.png" class="upArrow"/><img src="/assets/img/site/down_arrow.png" class="downArrow"/</li>');
  nameInput.value = '';
  nameInput.focus();
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div>
            <h4>
              <span class="text-muted">List</span>
            </h4>
            <ul id='list' class="list-group mb-3">
                
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-7 order-md-1">
            <form class="needs-validation row-form">
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="nazov">Name</label>
                <input id="f-name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="name" required>
              </div>
              <hr class="mb-4">
              <button>Submit</button>
            </form>
          </div>     
        </div>
      </main>
```

Comment: If you're just swapping, why am I seeing *append*?

Comment: You mean swapping their position after being inserted... Reordering by clicking arrow buttons?

Comment: Yes I mean swapping their position after being inserted. I am sorry for the incomplete question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reorder those dynamically added list' items using images (buttons) we set a [click](https://api.jquery.com/click/) handler by selecting their parent container first because those images are also dynamically added !

```
$('#list').on('click', '.downArrow', function(e) {
```

Then we use [insertAfter()](https://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) to move Down or [insertBefore()](https://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) to move Up their position in the list.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".p-title").hide().fadeIn(1500);
 const nameInput = document.querySelector('#f-name');
 nameInput.focus();
 
 $('form').on('submit', e=>{
  e.preventDefault(); 
  let name = nameInput.value; 
  addItem(name);
 })
 let addItem = (name)=>{
  $('#list').append('<li>'+name+'<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8b/Green_Arrow_Up_Darker.svg" class="upArrow"/ width="16"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/04/Red_Arrow_Down.svg" width="16" class="downArrow"/</li>');
  nameInput.value = '';
  nameInput.focus();
 }
  
$('#list').on('click', '.downArrow', function(e) {
var curLi = $(this).closest('li');
var tarLi = curLi.next('li');
curLi.insertAfter(tarLi);
});

$('#list').on('click', '.upArrow', function(e) {
var curLi = $(this).closest('li');
var tarLi = curLi.prev('li');
curLi.insertBefore(tarLi);
});



});
```

```css
body{
font-size:1.2em;
}
li:last-child img.downArrow,li:first-child  img.upArrow{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div>
            <h4>
              <span class="text-muted">List</span>
            </h4>
            <ul id='list' class="list-group mb-3">
                
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-7 order-md-1">
            <form class="needs-validation row-form">
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="nazov">Name</label>
                <input id="f-name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="name" required>
              </div>
              <hr class="mb-4">
              <button>Submit</button>
            </form>
          </div>     
        </div>
      </main>
```

[UPDATE] optimized the answer by changing the styling to hide button on the edges... which is better than doing it with jQuery. thanks to @[bhoodream](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1431312/bhoodream) comment

Comment: A cool answer, but I think that the arrows are better designed in styles than constantly switching using a script.

Comment: I'm just reusing his code :) Yeah buttons with fontawesome styles, SVGs.. or custom fontello icons are better.

Comment: I have svgs icon inside buttons in my code but I adjusted for this example. Stack overflow gave me a lot of errors for my primary code.

Comment: I see.. And you don't consider my answer as an accepted answer? :)

Comment: I do but I am new on this website so I don't know exactly how to use it ...

Comment: Sometimes you get multiple answers, you can upVote those you like and you better choose an accepted answer. Being grateful for the effort they gave to you. I even had an Unsung Hero badge cause of this :) many newcomers don't do that! Good luck :)